# Pandas: reshape data with duplicate row names to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that's sort of like this (first lines shown):

```
Sample  Detector        Cq
P_1   106    23.53152
P_1   106    23.152458
P_1   106    23.685083
P_1   135        24.465698
P_1   135        23.86892
P_1   135        23.723469
P_1   17  22.524242
P_1   17  20.658733
P_1   17  21.146122
```

Both "Sample" and "Detector" columns contain duplicated values ("Cq" is unique): to be precise, each "Detector" appears 3 times for each sample, because it's a replicate in the data.

What I need to do is to:

- Reshape the table so that the columns contain Samples and rows Detectors
- Rename the duplicate columns so that I know which replicate is it

I thought that `DataFrame.pivot` would do the trick, but it fails because of the duplicate data. What would be the best approach? Rename the duplicates, then reshape, or is there a better option?

EDIT: I thought over it and I think it's better to state the purpose. I need to store for each "Sample" the mean and standard deviation of their "Detector".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like what you may be looking for is a hierarchical indexed dataframe [[link]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex).

Would something like this work?

```
#build a sample dataframe
a=['P_1']*9
b=[106,106,106,135,135,135,17,17,17]
c = np.random.randint(1,100,9)
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=zip(a,b,c), columns=['sample','detector','cq'])

#add a repetition number column
df['rep_num']=[1,2,3]*( len(df)/3 )

#Convert to a multi-indexed DF
df_multi = df.set_index(['sample','detector','rep_num'])

#--------------Resulting Dataframe---------------------

                             cq
sample detector rep_num    
P_1    106      1        97
                2        83
                3        81
       135      1        46
                2        92
                3        89
       17       1        58
                2        26
                3        75
```

Comment: How do I pic `sample` based on `max(cq)` from this data \n
Say generate a new `df` : \n
`sample` `detector` `rep_num` `cq`\n
`p_1`       `106`      ` 1  `           `  97`