# Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex: efficient way of checking duplicate elements in one of the indices

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm working with data like this:

```
Sample  Detector        Cq
P_1   106    23.53152
P_1   106    23.152458
P_1   106    23.685083
P_1   135        24.465698
P_1   135        23.86892
P_1   135        23.723469
P_1   17  22.524242
P_1   17  20.658733
P_1   17  21.146122
```

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957593/pandas-reshape-data-with-duplicate-row-names-to-columns), I'm handling that with a MultiIndex. However, I'm wondering how, with such a structure, do some additional checks. Let's explain better: each "Sample" column has a fixed number of repeated "Detector" elements, from 1 (no duplication) to several duplicated elements. I want to ensure that for each sample element, the number of detectors is always the same (i.e., if P_1 has 3 "106" detectors, P_2 should have 3 "106" detectors as well).

Currently I'm doing this rather crudely:

```
def replicate_counter(dataframe, name):
    subset = dataframe.ix[name]
    num_replicates = subset.index.size / subset.index.unique().size
    return num_replicates

# Further down...
# dataframe is a MultiIndex DataFrame like above
counts = pandas.Series([replicate_counter(dataframe, item[0]) for item
                        in dataframe.index]).unique()

if counts.size != 1:
    raise ValueError("Detectors not equal for all samples")
```

It seems very hacky to me and probably there are better ways to do this in pandas. How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out `groupby` is what is needed to make this clear and concise (and probably more efficient too):

```
counts = dataframe.groupby(level=["Sample", "Detector"])
counts = counts.size().unique()

if counts.size != 1:
    raise ValueError("Detectors not equal for all samples")
```